# Transition between raytracing and physical(wave) optics

Tags: optics, simulations, geometric-optics, fiber-optics

In the past I have done raytracing simulations for large things, and physical optics (FEM, FDTD) for small wavelength-scale things.

Now I have a very large lens that focuses down on a waveguide. I have a raytracing model that spits out an "intensity map" of where the rays will hit on the waveguide face. The waveguide is still 100x larger than the wavelength. The NA of the waveguide is larger than the lens, so I believe all the light will enter the waveguide. (Do I have that correct?)

I now need to propagate this light in the waveguide for some distance. If it were a simple step-index waveguide I could just continue to use raytracing and the problem is done. But it is a very complicated structure with spatially-varying refractive indices -- basically FDTD is what I need.

Can I just take the "intensity map" of impinging rays from raytracing, and use that as my "source" for FDTD? I think no, because the intensity map doesn't have any information about which direction the rays are traveling, and it's from millions of rays rather than a wave. But I can think of no other way to do it.

Comment: You might try backing up further, where the rays can be more easily transformed into waves; ultimately this depends upon the software you are using.  Probably best to contact tech support and ask for advice.

Answer (score 2):

You are not the first to question this; see for example the work by Leiner et al. from [2013](http://dx.doi.org/10.1117/12.2017423) and [2014](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/JLT.2013.2297411).

Here the Ray Tracing technique is interfaced to Finite Difference Time Domain (FDTD) Maxwell simulations with ''**the Poynting vector representation of either rays or wave propagation directions**''.

As noted in these works you should be aware of the absence of phase information in the RT method, which might influence your results.